# Extract data from CSV with Regex and convert it to JSON

Tags: regex, json, qt, csv

Imagine you have a table in a CSV file with this kind of layout:

```
name,property1 [unit1],property2 [unit2]
name1,4.5,2.3
name2,3.2,7.4
name3,5.5,6.1
```

I need to convert each row to this kind of JSON structure (ie, for row 1):

```
{
    "name1": [
        {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property_1": "_value_",
                    "unit": "unit1"
                },
                {
                    "property_2": "_value_",
                    "unit": "unit2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

On top of it all, I have to explain that I am using Qt 4.7 and can't update; also, I can't install Qxt so I'm relying on [qt-json](https://github.com/ereilin/qt-json) for the JSON parsing/encoding. More, the CSV file is not created/maintained by me, so I can't really change it either.

So with all of this, I realised I need a few things, so this is a kind of multiple question:

- how should I write the RegEx to read the *unit* in each column's header? Please note that the *unit* is enclosed in rect-parenthesis.
- imagine I extract both the header row and the other rows into a `QList<QString>`, separating each column as a string. How can I manage to sync all the bits of data in order to create the JSON structure I need on a QString? (I think I need it in a QString so I can dump each row in a different file, but I'm open to other options as well)

Just one final note - I also need to this to be somewhat scalable. The CSV files on which this will be apllied are very heterogenous in column count: some have 8 columns, others have 20.

I know it is not a good practice to post "multiquestions", but the thing is I'm feeling too overwhelmed with all of this, and because I have virtually no experience with Qt, I can't even define a plan to attack this. Hope someone can share some pointers. Thanks!

**EDIT**
So, I've been thinking a little more about this and I don't actually know if this is a good idea/feasible but here is what I thought of:

- when going through the header row, I would check if each column string had a hit for the RegEx. If so, I would store the column index and the *unit* string in a list;
- then, when going through the other rows, in order to parse them into JSON, I would check in each column if it matched the index in the previous list, and if so, I would then add the *unit* to the map (as qt-json docs explains)

Does this make any sense? Can anyone mock up a skeleton I can work on for this?

**EDIT2**

I've managed to get a few things working so far, but still not working as it should. Right now I have managed to read properly from the CSV file, but the output isn't coming out right. Can anyone share some insight?

NOTE: the *processLineFromCSV* function returns a QStringList obtained like so: `QStringList cells = line.split(separator_char);`

NOTE2: the RegEx was obtained from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040766/find-substr-between-delimiter-characters-in-qt-with-regex) answer.

NOTE3: Check below for the type of output I'm getting. Right now I think the problem relates more to the usage of the `qt-json` lib than actually the rest of the code, but any help is welcome! :)

The code so far:

```
QFile file(csvfile);

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        bool first = true;
        QVariantMap map;
        QVariantMap propertyMap;
        QList<QVariant> generalList, propertiesList;

        while (!file.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = file.readLine();
            if(first == true){
                headerList = processLineFromCSV(line, separator_char);
                first = false;
            }else{

            QStringList cellList = processLineFromCSV(line, separator_char);

            int i=0;

            for(i; i<cellList.size(); i++)
            {
                // check the header cell for "[unit]" string
                // returns -1 if does not have the string
                // if it has the string, it's stored in capturedUnits[1]
                int test = exp.indexIn(headerList.at(i));

                // store the captured units in a QStringList
                QStringList capturedUnits = exp.capturedTexts();

                if(test==-1){ // if header does not have a captured unit - general column
                    QString name = headerList.at(i);
                    QString sanitizeName= name.remove(exp.capturedTexts().at(0), Qt::CaseSensitive);
                    map[sanitizeName] = cellList.at(i);
                }
                else{ // if header string has a captured unit - property column

                    QString propertyName = headerList.at(i); // extract string in header
                    QString sanitizedPropertyName = propertyName.remove(exp); //remove the unit regex from the string
                    sanitizedPropertyName.remove(QChar('\n'), Qt::CaseSensitive); // clear newlines

                    if(sanitizedPropertyName.startsWith('"') && sanitizedPropertyName.endsWith('"'))
                    {
                        sanitizedPropertyName.remove(0,1);
                        sanitizedPropertyName.remove(sanitizedPropertyName.length(),1);
                    }

                    QString value =cellList.at(i); // extract string in value
                    QString sanitizedValue = value.remove(QChar('\n'), Qt::CaseSensitive); // clear newlines

                    if(sanitizedValue.startsWith('"') && sanitizedValue.endsWith('"'))
                    {
                        sanitizedValue.remove(0,1);
                        sanitizedValue.remove(sanitizedValue.length(),1);
                    }

                    propertyMap[sanitizedPropertyName]= sanitizedValue; // map the property: value pair
                    propertyMap["unit"] = capturedUnits.at(1); // map the unit: [unit] value pair

                    QByteArray general = QtJson::serialize(map); // serialize the pair for general column
                    QByteArray properties = QtJson::serialize(propertyMap); // serialize the pair for property column

                    QVariant genVar(general);
                    QVariant propVar(properties);

                    generalList.append(genVar);
                    propertiesList.append(propVar);
                }
            }
        }}
        QByteArray finalGeneral = QtJson::serialize(generalList);
        QByteArray finalProperties = QtJson::serialize(propertiesList);

        qDebug() << finalGeneral;
        qDebug() << finalProperties;


        file.close();
    }
```

The ouput:

```
"[
    "{ \"name\" : \"name1\" }",
    "{ \"name\" : \"name1\" }",
    "{ \"name\" : \"name2\" }",
    "{ \"name\" : \"name2\" }",
    "{ \"name\" : \"name3\" }",
    "{ \"name\" : \"name3\" }"
]" 
"[
    "{ \"property1 \" : \"4.5\", \"unit\" : \"unit1\" }",
    "{ \"property1 \" : \"4.5\", \"property2 \" : \"2.3\", \"unit\" : \"unit2\" }",
    "{ \"property1 \" : \"3.2\", \"property2 \" : \"2.3\", \"unit\" : \"unit1\" }",
    "{ \"property1 \" : \"3.2\", \"property2 \" : \"7.4\", \"unit\" : \"unit2\" }",
    "{ \"property1 \" : \"5.5\", \"property2 \" : \"7.4\", \"unit\" : \"unit1\" }",
    "{ \"property1 \" : \"5.5\", \"property2 \" : \"6.1\", \"unit\" : \"unit2\" }"
]"
```

Comment: quote 'because I have virtually no experience with Qt', well first how would you attack the problem in your prefered language? Use this as your outline, and search the QT docs for 'equivalent' functions.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth right now I'm still trying to figure out how to read from the CSV file to a QList<QString>, but it's almost done. After this, I need to read the header row and the others separately because I need to filter the strings in the first row with a RegEx (which I never did before). Then the biggest problem I'm anticipating is how do I get everything in sync - I mean, I need to go through the several columns in the CSV file but, at the same time get the corresponding _unit_ for the value... I'm lost! :)

Comment: @DaveM that is good advice, true. Unfortunately I should have been more honest: my experience is with HTML and CSS. When it comes to JS, I usually rely on SO to solve my needs without having to ask any questions, but I don't really _code_ that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start for you:

```
QString csv = "name,property1 [unit1],property2 [unit2],property3 [unit3]\n"
              "name1,4.5,2.3\n"
              "name2,3.2,7.4\n"
              "name3,5.5,6.1,4.3\n";

QStringList csvRows = csv.split('\n', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
QStringList csvHeader = csvRows.takeFirst().split(',');
csvHeader.removeFirst();

foreach(QString row, csvRows) {
    QStringList values = row.split(',');
    QString rowName = values.takeFirst();

    QVariantList properties;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        QString value = values[i];
        QStringList propParts = csvHeader[i].split(' ');
        QString propName = propParts[0];
        QString propType = propParts[1].mid(1, propParts[1].size() - 2);

        QVariantMap property;
        property[propName] = value;
        property["unit"] = propType;

        properties.append(property);
    }

    QVariantMap propertyObj;
    propertyObj["properties"] = properties;
    QVariantList propList;
    propList.append(propertyObj);

    QVariantMap root;
    root[rowName] = propList;

    QByteArray json = QtJson::serialize(root);
    qDebug() << json;

    // Now you can save json to a file
}
```

Comment: Hi! This serves perfectly for my example, but if I try with a csv file that has more columns, it blows up with this error:`ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file c:\Progra~2\Qt\2010.04\qt\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 447
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.` any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: My example will fail if a row contains more properties than the header line. i.e. `name3,5.5,6.1,4.3 <= 3 properties` with header `name,property1 [unit1],property2 [unit2] <= 2 properties`. You just need to check that `i` is never larger than `csvHeader.size()`.

Comment: got it... posted the final answer below, but marked your code as correct answer, since my answer was based on yours. Thank you very, very much! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Joum.

Just seen your response to my comment. I don't have much experience with QT either, but a quick outline....

Extract the data one line at a time, and 'split' it into an array. If you are using CSV you need to be sure that there are no data points that have a comma in them, or the split will result in a real mess. Check with whoever extracted the data if they can use another 'less common' separator (eg a '|' is good). if you data is all numeric that is great, but be wary of locations that use the comma as a decimal separator :(

I hope that you have 1 'table' per file, if not you need to be able to 'identify' when a new table starts somehow, this could be interesting / fun - depends on your outlook ;).

At the end you will have a collection of 'string arrays' (a table of some sort) hopefully the first is your header info. If you have mutliple tables, you will deal with them one at a time

You should now be able to 'output' each table in good JSON format.

Getting your 'units' from the header rows: If you know in advance where they are located (ie the index in the array) you can plan for extracting the info (using a regex if you wish) in the correct index locations.

Last point.
If your csv file is very long (hundreds of lines), just grab the first few into a new test file for quicker debuging, then once you are happy, enlarge it a bit and check the output format... then again once you are happy that there are no other bugs... for the whole file
Likewise if you have multiple tables in your file, start with the first one only, then add the first part of a second... test.... add a third.... test etc etc etc until you are happy

David.

A possibly better solution, after reading your comment about wanting some form of 'synchronisation'.
NOTE: this may seem a little more complex, but I think it would be a more flexible solution in the end. Also does this data not exist in a DB somewhere (who gave it to you?), can they give you direct read access to the underlying DB and tables? if so, you can jump straight to the 'output each table to JSON' step.

using an embeded DB (ie SQLite).
Extract the first 'header' row, and create a table in your DB that follows the info there (you should be able to add info regarding units to the 'metadata' ie a description). If all your files are the same you could even import all the data into the same single table, or auto create a new table (assuming the same format) for each new file using the same create table statement.

I'm sure there is a 'csvimport' in SQLite (I haven't checked the docs yet, and haven't done this in a while) or someone has written a library that will do this.

Output each table to JSON format, again I'm sure someone has written a library for this.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I actually have different files for different tables, so that really isn't an issue. The tables aren't that big either, I would say around 30~40 rows each. Is there anything you can share about keeping the data sync'd? ie, having property_1 with it's respective value and unit? the unit will be in the header row, how can I get it from there?

Comment: Different Tables in Different files. Makes life much easier. Synchronising everything...a really neat solution... go mad and use a temp DB for storing the info, you may even find that a solution already exists for going from csv directly to the DB. The DB will be able to hold meta data descriptions about each column (ie its units). And may even have an 'output to json' library available. I would have a look at SQLite, I've used it and its reasonably simple, depends on how 'urgent' this is required.  In fact that may be the best solution.  See my edit.

Comment: Not really an option. The workstation I'm working on does not allow for software install. I have to stick with what I got. And I am actually doing all of this to get away from DBs, it isn't very functional for what I need, plus, I don't have much time to waste on this, because this is a very small part of the application.

Comment: @joum I added the DB idea into my response, in case someone else stumbles onto your question. As I say in my edit, where did the data originate? Otherwise, you are going to need to create new objects that have a collection, check the QT docs : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/containers.html you'll probably end up with either a QMap or QHash (ie a set of key to value pairs)... I must get back to working in QT.

Comment: The CSV tables come directly from an XLS spreadsheet being used by a mechanical engineer - that is the reason why I don't control it. It does not exist in a DB whatsoever. Plus, I am not able to install/use SQLite in this project. I +1'd your answer because, while not specifically what I need, I seems like a good approach and a very viable solution.

Comment: Ask your engineer if he can ouput to a '|' bar separated list, it will make your life easier in case of unexpected commas, or you may find a library that will directly export xls into JSON.

Comment: actually my prototype already asks the user which delimiter is being used.. :) I'm already figuring out a solution, I'll post it here for reference as well.

Comment: Glad to hear you are 'getting on with it'. When you post your own code remember to accept it as the correct answer. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer by ExplodingRat this is the final code: (without file creation at the end)

```
QString csvfile = ui->lineEditCSVfile->text();
    QString separator_char = ui->lineEditSeparator->text();
    QRegExp exp("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");

    QFile file(csvfile);
     if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         return;

    QString csv = file.readAll();

    QStringList csvRows = csv.split('\n', QString::SkipEmptyParts);

    QStringList csvHeader = csvRows.takeFirst().split(separator_char);

    csvHeader.removeFirst();

    foreach(QString row, csvRows) {
        QStringList values = row.split(separator_char);

        QString rowName = values.takeFirst();

        QVariantList general;
        QVariantList properties;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            QString value = values[i];

            int test = exp.indexIn(csvHeader[i]);
            //qDebug() << test;

            //qDebug() << csvHeader;
            QStringList capturedUnits = exp.capturedTexts();
            QString propName = csvHeader[i];


            if(test==-1){
                //QString propName = csvHeader[i].remove(exp);
                //qDebug() <<"property name" << propName;

                QVariantMap property;
                property[propName] = value;
                general.append(property);
            }else{
                propName.remove(exp);
                //QStringList propParts = csvHeader[i].split(' ');
                //QString propName = csvHeader[i].remove(exp);
                QString propType = capturedUnits[1];

                QVariantMap property;
                property[propName] = value;
                property["unit"] = propType;

                properties.append(property);
            }
        }

        QVariantMap propertyObj;
        propertyObj["properties"] = properties;
        QVariantList propList;
        propList.append(propertyObj);

        QVariantMap generalObj;
        generalObj["general"] = general;
        QVariantList generalList;
        generalList.append(generalObj);

        QVariantList fullList;
        fullList.append(generalObj);
        fullList.append(propertyObj);

        QVariantMap root;
        root[rowName] = fullList;

        QByteArray json = QtJson::serialize(root);

        json.prepend('[');
        json.append(']');

        qDebug() << json;

        // Now you can save json to a file
```