# Find substr between delimiter characters in Qt with RegEx

Tags: regex, qt, substring

I need to obtain a substring in a string in Qt, but with a few details:

- the substring I need is delimited by `[` and `]`
- the substring might have some unpredictable characters like `/`, `^`, `-`. This substring basically describes a *unit* of measurement.

Also, besides obtaining the substring itself, I need to have a test to check if such a substring exists in the string or not.

I don't know anything about RegEx and I'm new to Qt as well. Most of the examples I found here don't report to Qt and/or don't explicitly account for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QRegExp exp("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");
QString s1 = "5 [sm^2]";
qDebug() << exp.indexIn(s1);
qDebug() << exp.capturedTexts();
```

Output:

```
2 
("[sm^2]", "sm^2")
```

If none of the string's parts match the regexp, `indexIn` will indicate that by returning -1. Otherwise the result will be >= 0, and the `capturedTexts()[1]` will contain the text that was enclosed in brackets.